# Ubuntu landscape upgrades are not available after "apt update"

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, apt

This morning I received the following email from Ubuntu Landscape:

```
The following security upgrades are available:

Package                        Version              USN
-------------------------------------------------------------------
libapache2-mod-php7.2          7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-cli                     7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-common                  7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-dev                     7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-gd                      7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-json                    7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-mbstring                7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-mysql                   7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-opcache                 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-readline                7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
php7.2-xml                     7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.0 USN-4239-1
```

but on the VPS *(with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS)* in which Ubuntu Landscape is installed, after doing `apt update`, I get the message `All packages are up to date`.

The complete output is:

```
# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

`apt-cache show php7.2-cli` reports that the version installed is `7.2.3-1ubuntu1`, confirming that this package is not updated to `7.2.24`.

Do you think there is an explanation? Thank you

Comment: I edited the question adding the complete output of `apt update`.

Comment: Five days after, the issue is solved: now all packages are updated. I'm not sure why, maybe the repository mirror used by my Ubuntu Server installation wasn't immediately updated.